# Iterate between row column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
+-------------+------------+
| CustomerKey | ComTypeKey |
+-------------+------------+
|        5189 |          3 |
|        5189 |          4 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I want to set a bit variable and return 1 or 0 depending of result

```
DECLARE @CanHaveDeliveryContact BIT
```

My desire result is: if table has values 3 and 4 in any row my bit variable should be 1 if not just 0

Example case 1

```
+-------------+------------+
| CustomerKey | ComTypeKey |
+-------------+------------+
|        5189 |          3 |
|        5189 |          4 |
|        5189 |          1 |
|        5189 |          6 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Here I got many values but I I have 3 and 4 so my variable should be 1

Example case 2

```
+-------------+------------+
| CustomerKey | ComTypeKey |
+-------------+------------+
|        5189 |          3 |
|        5189 |          1 |
|        5189 |          6 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Here I just have value 3 but 4 is not there, so my variable should be 0

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'#Temp',N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp;
GO
SELECT 1 
INTO #Temp
FROM table 
WHERE comtypekey = 3

SELECT 1 
INTO #Temp
FROM table 
WHERE comtypekey = 4

DECLARE @count int = Select count(*) from #Temp 
DECLARE @CanHaveDeliveryContact BIT

IF @count = 2
SET @CanHaveDeliveryContact = 1
```